# JMeter - Active threats over time

Tags: testing, graph, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

I am new to JMeter. I am working with it the last month. The problem that i am facing is with the graph that shows the active threats over time. What i want to achieve is a linear graph that will show that every 2 seconds a new threat is entering the application and do whatever it needs to do. My set up is as follow:

[image]

I can not add loop count to infinite as each user is executing different tasks that can be executed only once. It can not reuse the data and hit the services/tasks again with the use of the same user.

The process is:

- Login
- Get Requests
- Post requests

If i execute my scenario i am getting the following graph:

[image]

What i need to do in order to get something like the below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're dealing with the [Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html) which means that it will plot the first data point only **when first sampler reports its metrics**.

If your first request takes 10 seconds you will see the first dot in the Active Threads Over Time chart at 10 seconds when 3 users are online already.

So if you want to see "smooth" arrival of virtual users you need to add a "synthetic" sampler with a couple of milliseconds response time before your other samplers (for example a [Dummy Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-dummy-sampler-the-ultimate-guide/) will be a perfect match), this way listeners will take it as the starting point

Demo:

[image]

Comment: Yes is working. The problem now is that i see in my results (result tree, aggregate report etc.) the dummy sampler which is something that i need to avoid . Is there a way to not show in my results the dummy sampler?

Comment: Another problem that i am facing is to run the five threats by sending one request and hold the load for a a minute (keep 5 threats alive until the minute pass).